# Musnad al-Rabī

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith

Can you mention scholars who authenticated this hadith other than al albani and any other source of this hadith

Ibn Abbas reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Reflect deeply upon the creation, but do not reflect upon the essence of the Creator. Verily, His essence cannot be known other than to believe in it.”
Source: Musnad al-Rabī’ 742
Grade; Hasan (fair) according to Al-Albani

Which book is musnad al-rabi i have never seen it anywhere who is its author i have read that this book is related to ibadis (branch of kharijite) what is its reputation among scholars of ahle sunna wal jamat

Arabic text-

عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صَلَّى اللَّهُ عَلَيْهِ وَسَلَّمَ تَفَكَّرُوا فِي الْخَلْقِ وَلا تَتَفَكَّرُوا فِي الْخَالِقِ فَإِنَّهُ لا يُدْرَكُ إِلا بِتَصْدِيقِهِ
742 مسند الربيع بن حبيب
2976 المحدث الألباني خلاصة حكم المحدث حسن في صحيح

I read this hadith on
Link-https://www.abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2017/02/14/tafakkur-creation-allah-essence/

Another hadith in same book -https://islamqa.org/hanafi/hadithanswers/123562/musnad-rabi-ibn-habib/

Comment: https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/260258/

Comment: Thanku that was good but can you provide something related to musnad ar rabi